# python script to get the instance ID from csv files and start the instance

Tags: python, csv, boto3

I have csv files which has multiple ec2 instance IDs...
is there any way I can run python script and fetch all the instance id and start all of them ..

Comment: Maybe you'll be able to share a few lines of your CSV so we know how it looks? And also an example of how you start a single one?

Comment: csv file looks like this:
Instance Ids
i-04b4ec7
i-096f714
i-3b8f8a3
i-07c2eab
i-0b22f0fd
i-0f9625e
i-0e4039f
i-05d857
.......
................
I need a script so that I can start these instance (use Instance IDs in the CSV) from the python script.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add in the CSV example in there where it will be properly formatted and legible. Also please answer the second part of my initial question. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear.. Let me give you an example.. I have report in which I have multiple Ec2 instance I have to work on.. So in order to work on those ec2, I have to restart the instance from aws console which I don't want to do that.. I need a script which can take instance ID from that csv file and start all of them.. You can put ec2 instance id in any csv file for yoru convenience . I just need a script which can take ec2 instance ID from csv or any other file format.. and start (without manual interruption)

Comment: Good. So please click `edit` under your question and add a few lines of your CSV and show the command you would use to start one.

Comment: you can assume any instance ID like I am assuming list in the csv file.. you can start the instance from this "
ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds = ['i-0bd9814668','i-4b8c36e40b'])"

Comment: It's very unlikely your question will get answered if you persist in putting everything in the comments area. You need to click `edit` under your question and put all the information in your question - **not in the comments**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a rather straightforward task.

1. Read all rows from CSV.
2. Submit call to EC2 using the extracted info.

```
    import csv
    import boto3

    with open('instances.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        instances = [row["Instance Id"] for row in reader]
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

Comment: that's seems like solution but getting this error while saving this as python file "Unable to create process using '/user/bin/env python "C:\Users\rsingh\Desktop\startinstance.py""

Comment: @RohitSingh that looks like problem in your python environment setup. Also don't treat this like 100% ready solution, it's a blueprint, you will more than likely need to tweak it a bit for your particular case.